# Error using mesh, matlab

Tags: matlab, mesh

I keep getting this error:

Error using mesh (line 76)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

here is code:

```
f = @(x,y)( get( handles.funkcja , 'string' ) );
[x,y] = meshgrid([-10:1:10],[-10:1:10]);
mesh(x,y,f(x,y));
```

example of `handles.funkcja`: x.^2+y.^2

Answer (score 0):

At a guess,

```
get( handles.funkcja , 'string' )
```

is returning a string. You can test this by checking whether

```
f(1,2)
```

returns

```
ans =

    x.^2+y.^2
```

It should return

```
ans =

    5
```

You could potentially fix this problem with

```
f = @(x,y)( eval(get( handles.funkcja , 'string' )) );
```